# What are your favourite examples of content with a rich taxonomy+metadata?

Tags: categorization, taxonomy

I'm designing for content where the taxonomy + metadata have never been put to good use in this subject matter.

I'm seeking inspiration beyond wikipedia: where a curated taxonomy + metadata (not user generated) have richly enhanced the browsing experience of the content.

I'm not interested in the metadata itself, just how its been used in the interface.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give some examples of non-user-generated metadata? Do you mean things like page views?

Comment: I mainly meant to exclude 'folksonomy' - e.g. tagging.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The BBC have been working hard on their BBC Wildlife section for a while - eg see top level section for:

- [Animals](http://www.bbc.co.uk/nature/animals/)
- [Species](http://www.bbc.co.uk/nature/species)
- [Habitats](http://www.bbc.co.uk/nature/habitats)
- [Adaptations and behaviours](http://www.bbc.co.uk/nature/adaptations).

They've been using domain driven design<sup>*[book](http://domaindrivendesign.org/books/evans_2003)*</sup> over traditional taxonomic architectures, and organizing information by *things* and their *relationships* rather than by documents for example.

Comment: ah thanks. Reminds me of this: http://www.slideshare.net/reduxd/beyond-the-polar-bear

Comment: So it should :-) - I've seen Mike give this presentation live and I think the BBC have done a really good job.